# How to use tesseract output from an image to create searchable pdf from another image

Tags: pdf, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a png image which I improve for better tesseract OCR quality and afterwards I need to make a searchable pdf from the original image.

I am able to create a searchable pdf from the improved image with tesseract using this python code:

```py
f = open("programme.pdf", "w+b")
file = sys.argv[1]

black_and_white = create_black_and_white(image=file, threshold=150) # function converting the image to black and white with some filtering
pdf = pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr(black_and_white, config=custom_tesseract_config, extension='pdf')
f.write(bytearray(pdf))

f.close()
```

However, what I would like is not to create a PDF with the black and white image I create, but to use the tesseract output from that b&w image and add the result into the original image and make that one into a searchable pdf. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid question where I only showed that I did not think through what I was trying to accomplish.

I solved the problem by simply adding the result b&w pdf produced by the code in the question as a background into a pdf created from the original file. To do that I used the `pdftk` utility.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code for the same?